# Scripts to create SQL Server 2008 stored procedure and sql agent job not recognizing server qualification syntax

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

```
SELECT * from [MCSOWS20\SQL2008].Tax_KY.dbo.bills
```

I run this where [MCSOWS20\SQL2008] is a linked server object. It runs fine if I just run it in a new query window on the calling server.

If I try to use the above qualified server and database in a use statement, like this: `USE [MCSOWS20\SQL2008].Tax_KY`, the procedure that contains it, which is creating stored procedures, throws a sql error indicating the 'database does not exist', and it does not create the sql agent job and stored procedure where [MCSOWS20\SQL2008].Tax_KY is being used. SQL Agent is turned on for both machines.

Any ideas why it won't work? The linked servers on both sides test out to a good connection.

Comment: USE statements only work within the DB server context you're currently in. In other words, you cannot use `USE` to specify a DB on a linked server. You have to actually connect to the server.

Comment: OK. That should be okay to fix one of these issues, thanks. I want to look closer at the other one to see if it applies there as well. Thanks. I will post results of this in a few minutes.

Comment: I usually make a View to wrap the remote DB + table, or I make a Synonym.  Do you have that option?

Comment: I don't think I can-- we're replicating several tables off a database on one server across to a database on the other server. Manually affecting the design of the subscriber often breaks replication, at least if you manually modify tables that were replicated. Driscoll's first suggestion worked okay for us. The second concern I had was satisfied due to the main server needing to run the job I was trying to run from the destination server, so all of that is fixed now. I'm working on getting the replication to run at this point. Thanks for the help.